# Is there a flat-file database that is supported by Silverlight?

Tags: c#, database, silverlight, sqlite

I am looking for a flat-file (or serverless) database that I can connect to a C# Silverlight application.

There has to be one, but I can't find anything.

**EDIT:** SQLite is an example of a flat-file database. A flat-file database in my view is any database that does not require a server. Unfortunately, SQLite does not work with Silverlight.

What I want to achieve is to be able to store, update and delete entries from the database. In my application, there is a chart with sectors and nodes. I want to be able to edit sectors and store their settings in the database, and I want to be able to add/retrieve/edit/delete nodes on the chart.

The database needs to be free for educational purposes.

**EDIT:** This database I need for use on a cellphone. So there can't be any service that listens. When I say "serverless", I mean serverless, I cannot use even a localhost server. It needs to read data from a file and write to the file.

Thanks.

Comment: Your use of the term "flat-file" is confusing in this context. Are you looking for an embeddable database?

Comment: Can you give some more details on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at these:

- http://siaqodb.com/
- http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/

Comment: I've been using csharp-sqlite and it is amazing!  I'm amazed its getting so little attention.

Answer (score 0):

See also:

- http://sterling.codeplex.com/
- http://silverdb.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft just released SQL Server CE 4.0, which can be used in the manner I think you want.

[ScottGu's blog - SQL CE](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/11/vs-2010-sp1-and-sql-ce.aspx)

As an aside, I believe a flat-file database is one consisting of tables with no relationships defined between them (i.e. an Excel spreadsheet).

Comment: Unless I'm missing something (always a strong possibility), I don't think that SQL CE can be used directly with Silverlight.  You need something like the four databases mentioned in the other answers, which run directly inside Silverlight.  I haven't seen any indication that SQL CE runs inside the Silverlight CLR.

Answer (score 0):

> A flat-file database in my view is any
>   database that does not require a
>   server.

None of the free versions of SQL database management systems require a server. All of them can be installed on your desktop or laptop. Expect them to run a background service that "listens" for you to try to make a connection to their databases, though.

I've heard of some people doing lightweight storage using XML. I don't know how much grief it is for Silverlight apps.

I'd expect Silverlight to play more politely with some version of Microsoft's SQL Server.

If you're using Microsoft technology for educational purposes, you might already have a site license that includes Microsoft Access. (This observation thrown in for completeness.)

As far as I know, all these are free of cost, regardless of their use. In the olden days, some high-end SQL dbms had free versions that could be used for evaluation and development, but couldn't legally be used for commercial purposes. As far as I know, none of these have that restriction nowadays. So, unless I've missed something, they're all free for educational purposes. Some of them limit database size, some limit the number of processors, etc.

Anyway, in no particular order . . .

- [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/)
- [Oracle XE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/express-edition/overview/index.html)
- [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/)
- [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/)
- [DB2 Express-C](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/express/)
- [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/index.html)
- [Teradata Express](http://www.teradata.com/t/teradata-express/)
- [Greenplum Community Edition](http://www.greenplum.com/products/community-edition/)

Comment: I think the "does not require a server" part refers to actually having to install something that runs in the background.

Comment: You could be right. SQL CE promises to work that way, but I can't install it here. Not sure why--possibly because I have SQL Server installed? The other embedded dbms I know of don't support ASP.NET for various reasons, and Silverlight needs that support, right?

Comment: ScimoreDB Embedded supports ASP.NET. http://www.scimore.com/products/embedded.aspx

Comment: I don't think that *any* of these are relevant to the question, which specifies that the database must work directly with Silverlight.  And so far as I know, none of the products mentioned do that.  They all require a web service to sit between the db and the Silverlight application, which is precisely what the OP wants to avoid.

Comment: @Ken Smith: After reading the OP's edits, I'm pretty sure you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered interacting with a text file directly with file I/O?

Answer (score 0):

The fully-managed [C# port of SQLite3](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/) works with Silverlight.

It is serverless and meets your other stated needs. It is available under the open-source [MIT license](http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php).